# Angular 2 error Map is not defined

Tags: javascript, angular, xbox-one

I edited my question because it was not clear enough (I think)

I have a simple app in angular2 and I try to run it on Xbox (yes it's possible with the development kit and Visual Studio). I know it works with an angular 1.5 app because I already succeed. So, this is my stack trace when the code run (sorry my VS is partially in french) :

[image]

This is my index.html :

[image]

And this is my systemjs.config.js :

[image]

Because I need to push my app on Xbox I had all js files I need in my visual jsproject BUT I think I forgot one but I don't know which one so... If you have an idea. Thank you !! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess is that you need to load the ES6 shim in your index.html file(as explained [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/browser-support.html)).

```
<script src="../node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
```

Place it before the zone.js script line(or even base.js).

Comment: Thank you so much ! I had a lot of exceptions thrown during the lauch but it works !!!!

I put it before core.js but after Microsoft libraries and I add it to my jsproj (important, without that it's not working)